# Create a workflow in SharePoint

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, document-library, email

I am new to the SharePoint technology. I need to create a workflow when a new document has been uploaded to the document library, it should fire an email to a particular user. How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Here is link to get you started with developing workflows with Sharepoint designer:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx

You can easily create workflows in Designer and use workflow action 'Send an e-mail message' to reach your goal.

If you have any additional questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use workflows for this basic actions, if you don't want to change body of outgoing e-mails, try to use alerts, here is the page with step-by-step guide.

http://sharepointalert.info/2009/09/getting-started-with-sharepoint-alerts

You can setup alerts for new items only, for changes or for deleted items only.

Comment: +1 this is the simplest solution if you are interested only to notify certain users of new document uploads

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late a reply for this question but for the refernce of people who might open this question anywhere in future I would like to add a link which really helped me a lot in starting with workflows. It is an excellent resource for workflow related videos provided by Robert Shelton. 
Really very helpful if you are a beginner to workflows.

http://www.sheltonblog.com/archive/2007/11/04/series-of-sharepoint-workflow-how-to-videos.aspx

Regards,

Geetanjali